# React Native SectionList: render each section inside a container (View)

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

Is it possible to render each section in sectionlist inside a View container or give it styles?
What i want is something like this:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <Section>
      <SectionHeader />
      <SectionItem />
      <SectionItem />
      <SectionFooter />
   <Section>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`renderSectionFooter`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#rendersectionfooter) and [`renderSectionHeader`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#rendersectionheader).

Take a look at [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)

Comment: I already using these but what i want is to place these and items inside a Card view so i can use shadow and border radius for the whole section not just items.

Comment: Then you may want to use `borderBottomLeftRadius` and `borderBottomRightRadius` for your footer and Top Radius for your header. I think it's better to use `<FlatList>`.

Comment: What about elevation (shadow)?

Comment: I guess there is no easy way for that. That's why i recommended to use `<FlatList>`